# VS Code Arduino Extension: after switching to using bundled CLI, cannot compile

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, arduino-cli

I am using Arduino extension on Visual Studio Code on Mac.
The Arduino IDE version installed on my laptop is 1.8.19.
But I usually work through VS Code.

However, seems like Arduino extension on VS Code no longer support the Arduino IDE. (or will stop soon)
It suggested me to use the bundled Arduino CLI, which I switched to.
But ever since I switched it, I have problems compiling my code, spitting out the same lines of error messages that say:

**[Warning] Output path is not specified. Unable to reuse previously compiled files. Build will be slower. See README.
[Warning] Failed to generate IntelliSense configuration.**

It seems like it no longer auto-generate the c_cpp_properties.json
I am fairly new to this kind of issue so any suggestions will help :(

In the Arduino settings I checked that using the CLI is set to true and I left the default Arduino path blank as described in: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino